# Angular 15: Proxy Config not Working or Deducted

Tags: angular, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I freshly created a new Angular 15 App, and tried to run with proxy-config property but the proxy is not deducted or not working at all.

[image]

The source code is in

https://github.com/jonesprabu/custom-form-elements/blob/main/src/proxy.conf.json

The Api call is in

[https://github.com/jonesprabu/custom-form-elements/blob/main/src/app/services/manage-students.service.ts#:~:text=const%20students%24%20%3D%20this.http.get%3CStudent%5B%5D%3E(%60%24%7Benvironment.api%7D/students%60)%3B](https://github.com/jonesprabu/custom-form-elements/blob/main/src/app/services/manage-students.service.ts#:%7E:text=const%20students%24%20%3D%20this.http.get%3CStudent%5B%5D%3E(%60%24%7Benvironment.api%7D/students%60)%3B)

[image]

The actual working api:
[image]

Please help me in find where I am going wrong with this project?

Comment: could you provide an example of a call url? something like `localhost:3333/api/anything/123`

Comment: @Andrei i edited the question with some more info

Comment: but how would you acccess your api without a proxy? what is the correct url for getting students? I think you have proxy working, but the config is incorrect

Comment: If the proxy works then we will not get 404 right? some other server err should come, And we cant see any sign of proxy activated in the cmd and no log for the api call is coming in the cmd

Comment: @Andrei i added the actual api swagger screeshot as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with current config api call will be sent to `:3333/api/students` while what you want to get is just `:3333/students`. To achieve such behavior add pathRewrite option to the proxy config

```
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3333",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great! It worked. But why it is not displaying any log in the CMD? Any idea?

Comment: logging is off, unless `"verbose": true` is added to the proxy config. overal webpack proxy logging is not very good and helpfull in most cases

Comment: https://medium.com/@gagandeep.sidhu88/how-to-fix-logging-for-proxy-in-angular-834cf46d437d
found this article helpful to add logging as webpack has stopped logging from a particular version.